# Can I say "I take my son to school by car every day"?

Tags: phrase-request, usage

> I drive my son to school.

How to say it in correct English? Can I say "I drop my son"?

I am not on my way to work and return home after dropping him.

Answer (score 4):

You drop your son OFF.  The phrasal verb is 'drop off'.

Comment: Agreed, though it depends on what the OP means by 'correct English'. I wouldn't use 'drop off' in a formal letter, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you return home after delivering your son to school, I would say:

> I drive my son to school every day.

If, however, you delivered your son to school and then went on to another destination, I would say:

> I drop off my son at school every day.

"Drop off" implies a brief stop while en route to  destination, such as:

> Could you drop me off at the library on your way to the mall?

Note that "drop off" takes the preposition "at," not "to." The sentence "I drop off my son to school" is ungrammatical and would sound strange to native English speakers.

Comment: I think 'drop off' just implies that they get out and you quickly leave, rather than saying anything about the next destination. In the asker's case, the next destination is home.

Comment: Also, the second phrasing would be less awkward as "I drop my son off at" rather than "I drop off my son at". Your son is 'dropped', the 'off at' part says where, similar to the third phrasing: "drop *me* off at *the library*".

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to say this.

I would say:

> I drop my son off at school every day.

This is an idiomatic usage that makes it very clear that the son gets out of the car and then you promptly leave to go elsewhere. Where you're going next is unimportant. It could be work, home, or somewhere else. It's the second usage from [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/drop_off), although I was surprised when I was unable to find a second dictionary with that definition.

Less idiomatically, one might say:

> I drive my son to school every day.

This is a very clear and literal way of stating what you're doing.

Other possible forms include:

> I take my son to school every day.

Listeners will assume you're driving.

> I give my son a ride to school every day.

Giving someone "a ride" means that you're driving and they're your passenger. Listeners will assume a car unless context implies otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

> I take my son to school by car every day.

Be simple and don't miss articles.

> I go with my son to school every day.

Comment: I disagree that the article is required in "to school". In fact, "to the school" raises the question, "which school? is there only one?", whereas "to school" implies "to _his_ school" (or at least "the school I drive him to")

Comment: I am very bad with *articles* but use rule that _a_, _an_ is where something is not defined and _the_ where is defined - it looks that is not valid rule if _the_ could replace _his_. I am Polish we do not use articles at all so for me it strange in some case - thanks for hint.

Comment: The indefinite article is also used when referring to somebody/something that have not been already mentioned: "A man killed his wife and his daughter this morning." After that, you can say "The man said to the police he didn't want to kill them."

Comment: "I go with my son to school" would be more appropriate if you stayed at the school with your son, rather than dropping them off.